# coarse graining a graph (networkx)

Tags: python, matrix, graph, igraph, networkx

I am trying to coarse grain a large network to a smaller network by predefined node labels. say:

```
large_network = np.random.rand(100,100)
labels = [1,1,1,1,
          5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
          0,0,0,0,0, ...] #[1x100]
```

for example, we have 10 regions each having a few nodes.
something like membership list (in the network community detection algorithms in `networkx`), that tells each node belongs to which community, but here I am defining it manually. Then I need to calculate new reduced adjacency matrix say `[10x10]`.

So the average weights of edges between the regions A and B that `w_{AB} = mean(edges(A, B))` determine the weight of the edge between these two regions.

One way is to loop over edges of each node and if two endpoints of the edge were in the membership list of two regions, add it to the weighted sum.
Am I doing right?
Is there any better strightforward method?

Answer (score 1):

You could `coo_matrix` in `scipy.sparse` to do the job for you. The nice thing is that this approach can readily by extended to sparse network representations.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

# set parameters
N = 100 # no of nodes
M = 10  # no of types

# initialise random network and random node labels
weights = np.random.rand(N, N) # a.k.a "large_network"
labels = np.random.randint(0, M, size=N)

# get sum of weights by connection type
indices = np.tile(labels, (N,1)) # create N x N matrix of labels
nominator = coo_matrix((weights.ravel(), (indices.ravel(), indices.transpose().ravel())), shape=(M,M)).todense()

# count number of weights by connection type
adjacency = (weights > 0.).astype(np.int)
denominator = coo_matrix((adjacency.ravel(), (indices.ravel(), indices.transpose().ravel())), shape=(M,M)).todense()

# normalise sum of weights by counts
small_network = nominator / denominator
```